# Is it possible to assign different shortcuts to different tasks in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code allows multiple tasks to be defined in the `["tasks"]` array in `tasks.json` and the one with the property `isBuildCommand: true` gets given the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+B by default.

> I would like to assign different keyboard shortcuts to each of the tasks I've created. Is this possible, and if so how?

All I've found so far is the ability to assign a shortcut to the command `workbench.action.tasks.runTask` which will popup a menu of all the tasks in alphabetical order that I can up/down arrow through. I would like to configure Code to run each task directly with one key combination.

Comment: https://dlaa.me/blog/post/vscodenodetask had a nice example of a `tasks.json` file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there is one other property that can be used to bind a shortcut. Its name is `isTestCommand`. If set to true it bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to the task. We do have an internal work item to allow to bind arbitrary shortcuts to tasks.

Comment: Its not implemented yet, but there is [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6550) (milestone july 2016). So hopefully it will be available in july release.

Comment: You need to add this to keybindings.json:
[
{"key": "ctrl+shift+t", "command": "workbench.action.tasks.test"}
]

Comment: property of what?

Answer (score 64):

As of VS Code 1.10, you can use the `workbench.action.tasks.runTask` command in your keybindings, and pass in the task's name as your argument.

The [VS Code task documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_binding-keyboard-shortcuts-to-tasks) gives this example:

```js
{
    "key": "ctrl+h",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "build"
}
```

Comment: (just to add: this belongs in `keybindings.json`, not `tasks.json`, "args" actuall reflects your `"taskName"` in `tasks.json` and to my positive surprise: spaces are not a problem, i.e. `"args" : "Run Sample"` also works fine.)

Comment: The `taskName` is deprecated, you'll use the `label` instead. For example if you have a grunt type task with the name prod, you'll use `grunt: prod` in the args, as that's the default label for that.

Answer (score 24):

As of VSCode 1.19 (Feb 2018):

**In `/myproject/.vscode/tasks.json` you need to add a `label` (formerly, now deprecated: `taskName`) to your npm task.**

(I named my label the same as the `package.json` script I intend to run. But that's just personal style, not technical need):

```json
{
    "label": "ui",
    "type": "npm",
    "script": "ui"
}
```

**Then you reference that task by its label in your user keybindings** `/home/johndoe/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json`:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+r",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "ui"
}
```

In case you wondered: No, there are no project-level keybinding in vscode. [Reasons here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10708#issuecomment-241330047)

Comment: For macOS the location of `keybindings.json` seems `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/keybindings.json`. Better way to access it: Command palette (⇧⌘P) --> Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)

Answer (score 8):

I just submitted a PR for this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/10676

So once it's merged you will have the ability to assign any task to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Is this added yet? When I type `commandBinding` in my `task.json` I get the message that it is not allowed.