# Run Code on integrated terminal Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the following piece of code in my task.json:

```
    {
        "taskName": "Run",
        "suppressTaskName": true,
        "args": [
            "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Albedo"
        ]
    }
```

When I run "Run" the program starts as it is supposed to, but when I have `getchar()` in the code nothing happens when I the program it get stuck in the output. There is no place where I can press `Enter` to continue.

So I am thinking about how do I open the integrated terminal and run it from there? Would it be possible to call such a command from `task.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature was actually added in the upcoming January release, see [this section](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_9.md#task-execution-in-terminal) of the release notes draft. Essentially, you just have to add this to your `tasks.json`:

```
"_runner": "terminal"
```

If you don't want to wait until release (which should be soon) to check this out, you can use an [Insider's build](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders).

Comment: Do you know if it will possible to map keyboard short-cuts to different tasks as well?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057191/is-it-possible-to-assign-different-shortcuts-to-different-tasks-in-vs-code

Answer (score 1):

To interactively run code in the integrated terminal, either a single line at a time or multiple selected lines by simply pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, I did the following:

1. Install [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros)  extension.
2. Add the following to `User Settings`

```js
"macros": {
    "canCopyEmpty": [
        "expandLineSelection",
        "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
        "cancelSelection"
    ],
    "runLine": [
        "macros.canCopyEmpty",
        "workbench.action.terminal.paste",
        {
            "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
            "when": "terminalFocus"
        }
    ],
    "runSelection": [
        "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText",
        "cursorDown"
    ]
}
```

1. Add the following to `keybindings.json`

```js
{
    "key": "ctrl+enter",
    "command": "macros.runLine",
    "args": {
        "cmd": "ls",
        "match": ".*"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+enter",
    "command": "macros.runSelection",
    "args": {
        "cmd": "ls",
        "match": ".*"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection"
}
```

Comment: This is an old answer, and changes to the VSCode core broke the keybindings in the original answer.  I have updated it with `keybindings` and `user settings` that work with the most recent release of VSCode. Nothing to prevent future changes from breaking it again.