# "No matching commands" for custom VS Code task

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm trying to figure out how to create and use custom tasks.

I have been able to create a tasks.json file, but when I try to run the task from the command palette, nothing shows up.

My current **.vscode/tasks.json** file contains:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo Hello"
        }
   ]
}
```

I have also tried:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "New Test Task",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo 'hello new task'",
            "windows": {
                "command": "echo 'hello new task'"
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "new"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And I have also tried the following combinations of folder/file:

- **.vs/tasks.json**
- **.vs/tasks.vs.json**
- **.vscode/tasks.vs.json**
- **.vscode/tasks.json**

Despite all of this, I keep getting a "No matching commands" error message. Is there something that I have overlooked or am doing wrong? Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Screenshot:
[image: No matching commands]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command palette, it requires 2 (or 3) steps/commands.

First, you need to get "**Tasks: Run Tasks**" in the command palette.
(By just entering "*tasks*", you should see it)

[image: command palette > run tasks]

Then, after selecting that, it should list you all the tasks defined in your **.vscode/tasks.json** (yes, this is the correct folder/file combination as seen from the example in the [Custom Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks) section of the VS Code docs). Specifically, all the `label`'s defined in your **tasks.json**:

[image: command palette > list of tasks]

Now, depending on the task, it may prompt a third selection, like this one for your `echo` task:

[image: command palette > task options]

If you want a single-step/command, you can use the other options of the `Tasks:` command group such as re-running the last run task or configuring a default task:

[image: command palette > tasks options]

Or instead of the command palette, use a keybinding/shortcut to run your task: [Is it possible to assign different shortcuts to different tasks in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30057191/2745495).

Comment: Thank you so much. The solution was so simple. Everywhere I read, I was under the impression that it was a 1 step thing to run a task.

Answer (score 0):

you can add shortcut bindings to vscode's run task tasks.json by As in the following steps.

My OS environment is macOS
Use the shortcut "`shift+command+P`" to open the console
[image]

Then configure the shortcut key command as follows

```
{
  "key": "f8",
  "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
  // "args": "echo", // You can also define your task label directly
  "args": "${input}",
}
```

[image]

Finally, enter the shortcut key Use the shortcut key F8 to see the results of the task output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A bit simple but might help someone!

My colleague had by mistake clicked on `Run Test Task` and there nothing appeared. When clicking `Run Task` the stuff from `.vscode/tasks.json` appeared.

[image: VS Code screenshot]